# Output current html view to string when button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a print-ready view that renders nicely in the browser. It would be nice to offer users the option to click a link or button located on that view that would call an action to create a PDF from the raw HTML in the view. I have the PDF processing part figured out, I just need help figuring out:

1. When link or button is clicked, put the rendered HTML from that view into a string variable to be sent to my PDF processing code.

Here is my Controller method that renders the page:

```
 public ActionResult ViewReport(int? id, string memberID, int month, int year)
 {
            var task = new ViewReportTask();


            return View(task.BuildViewModel(id, memberID, month, year));
  }
```

The view is just a lot of html and razor code blocks so I did not include it here.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean the rendered HTML?  Just what you see in View Source on the page?

Comment: yes, exactly. just the html that gets rendered in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using following approach:

You have Action method which generates your View:

```
public ActionResult ViewReport(int? id, string memberID, int month, int year)
 {
            var task = new ViewReportTask(); 
            return View(task.BuildViewModel(id, memberID, month, year));
  }
```

Create one more ActionResult:

```
  public ActionResult PrintMyView(int? id, string memberID, int month, int year)
    {
      return new ActionAsPdf( "ViewReport", new { id= id; memberID=memberID; month=month; year=year})
{ FileName = "ViewReport.pdf"};
    }
```

To have `ActionAsPdf` method you need to install `Rotativa` Nuget Package:

> Install-Package Rotativa

Now to save your page as pdf user must click on following link on your view:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Save as PDF, "PrintMyView", "Home", new{id= id, memberID=memberID, month=month, year=year}, null) 
//** I can't see where you takes parameters in your view, so I just list them.
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: In your example don't you want commas instead of semi colons? new { id= id, memberID=memberID, month=month, year=year}